# Can start Pi but getting read-only file system

Tags: sd-card

I tried:

`mount -o remount, rw /` - it says `write-protected`

`fsck` - also not helped but no errors

And nothing of this not helped. Any ideas?

Note: i can write and format microsd when it plugged to my laptop.

Comment: What does the kernel log (via `dmesg`) say?

Comment: Have you checked whether the SD card could be [write locked](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1102/~/sd%2Fsdhc%2Fsdxc-memory-card-is-write-protected-or-locked) with the switch on the side? I assume you're using a microSD-to-SD adapter; check if there's a switch on that.

Comment: @Janka it say `Remounting filesystem read-only` (https://pastebin.com/aEx1ayMa)

Comment: @Aurora0001 yes i checked and it unlocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kernel log says:

```
mmcblk0: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0xe00
mmcblk0: not retrying timeout
end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 1220608
Buffer I/O error on device mmcblk0p2, logical block 131072
lost page write due to I/O error on mmcblk0p2
JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for mmcblk0p2-8.
fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

**end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 1220608**

See the problem? Your SD card is broken. Backup your user data from it, then overwrite it completely. It makes use from replacement erase blocks then. Re-write a fresh Raspian (or similar) image and restore your user data.

If it happens again, **throw away**.

Comment: Okay i'll try it. But its fun to hear because i bought this card 2 days ago.

Comment: It's most likely counterfeited then.

Comment: Well. Today i bought new card and everything working fine on it. Thank for your answer @Janka !